# Is calling Angular's $apply necessary after clicking bound directive to update controller $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

Snippets below, Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/WA6tIfqXV6dO4pbsqxu9?p=preview

A challenge I'm often facing is updating the controller scope from the directive scope upon firing a binding on the directive element, e.g. 'click'. I've got it working by calling $apply() after changing the directive's scope, but is that overkill?

So say I have a controller value aptly named "value":

```
  .controller( 'coolCtrl', [ '$scope', function( $scope )
  {
    $scope.value = 1;
  }])
```

And I want to increase that value from within a directive upon clicking the directive element:

```
  .directive( 'testScope', function()
  {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        value: '='
      },
      template: '<button>Increase value</button>',
      link: function( scope, element, attrs )
      {
        // Note: just using standard jqLite here
        element.on( 'click', function()
        {
          scope.value++;
          scope.$apply();
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

Is calling an $apply necessary to update the parent scope on every click? What if the user were typing, would the entire parent scope downwards have to go through a $digest cycle on each keydown?

PS my familiarity with Angular is humbling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the native browser events you have to use `$apply` to make the changes visible to angular. And yes, if you are using keydown a complete digest cycle will happen. But in most cases this is not a problem.

You may really reduce your code if you are using the build in ng-* directives. For example you may use `ng-click` for your problem:

```
.directive( 'testScope', function()
  {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        value: '='
      },
      controller: function($scope){
          $scope.increase = function(){
            $scope.value++;
          }
      },
      template: '<button ng-click="increase()">Increase value</button>'
    }; 
  })
```

If you go this way, there is no need for calling `$apply` manually. This is the angular way...

Comment: Thanks I suppose letting Angular know that the user has made a change makes sense. But it just seems like there are often a lot of moving parts on modern web apps and it'd be nice to focus on only what was changed. Thanks for the ng-click example.